# Why group_by and mutate(mean) not working in a large data in r

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, mean

The situation is: I was trying to calculate the mean of 3 values (ignore NA) in the value column based on the grouping of the Sample_ID column, but clearly, using group_by and mutate(mean) were not working here; the results were definitely wrong. I also tried the data.table method, but it was not working.

```
mdat_longer_info[ ,list(mean=mean(value, na.rm=T)), by=Sample_ID]
```

Below is the raw data (mdat_longer_info):

```
> print(mdat_longer_info, n=21)
# A tibble: 3,422,100 × 2
      value Sample_ID    
      <dbl> <chr>        
 1      NA  nist         
 2      NA  nist         
 3      NA  nist         
 4      NA  q3June2014_1a
 5      NA  q3June2014_1a
 6      NA  q3June2014_1a
 7      NA  269          
 8      NA  269          
 9      NA  269          
10 3803018. 270          
11      NA  270          
12      NA  270          
13      NA  303          
14      NA  303          
15      NA  303          
16      NA  140          
17      NA  140          
18      NA  140          
19      NA  129          
20 6497352. 129          
21      NA  129          
# … with 3,422,079 more rows
```

And below is the code I used:

```
mdat_longer_info %>%
  group_by(Sample_ID) %>%
  mutate(mean_value=mean(value, na.rm=T)) %>%
  print(n=21)
```

And below is the wrong result using my code:

```
# A tibble: 3,422,100 × 3
# Groups:   Sample_ID [186]
      value Sample_ID     mean_value
      <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
 1      NA  nist          196099407.
 2      NA  nist          196099407.
 3      NA  nist          196099407.
 4      NA  q3June2014_1a 277984587.
 5      NA  q3June2014_1a 277984587.
 6      NA  q3June2014_1a 277984587.
 7      NA  269           203239889.
 8      NA  269           203239889.
 9      NA  269           203239889.
10 3803018. 270           206941552.
11      NA  270           206941552.
12      NA  270           206941552.
13      NA  303           313751258.
14      NA  303           313751258.
15      NA  303           313751258.
16      NA  140           172154953.
17      NA  140           172154953.
18      NA  140           172154953.
19      NA  129           159086377.
20 6497352. 129           159086377.
21      NA  129           159086377.
# … with 3,422,079 more rows
```

I hope to generate results that fit these rules:

- 3 NA should generate NA or NAN 3 times
- 2 NA and 1 real number should generate the real number 3 times
- 1 NA and 2 real numbers should generate the average of the 2 real numbers 3 times
- 3 real numbers should generate the average of the 3 real numbers 3 times

Also, what makes me crazier is that when I sliced my huge data to a small data, my code worked, see below:

```
> mdat_longer_info1 = mdat_longer_info[1:21, ]
> mdat_longer_info1 %>%
+   group_by(Sample_ID) %>%
+   mutate(mean_value=mean(value, na.rm=T)) %>%
+   print(n=21)
# A tibble: 21 × 3
# Groups:   Sample_ID [7]
      value Sample_ID     mean_value
      <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
 1      NA  nist                NaN 
 2      NA  nist                NaN 
 3      NA  nist                NaN 
 4      NA  q3June2014_1a       NaN 
 5      NA  q3June2014_1a       NaN 
 6      NA  q3June2014_1a       NaN 
 7      NA  269                 NaN 
 8      NA  269                 NaN 
 9      NA  269                 NaN 
10 3803018. 270             3803018.
11      NA  270             3803018.
12      NA  270             3803018.
13      NA  303                 NaN 
14      NA  303                 NaN 
15      NA  303                 NaN 
16      NA  140                 NaN 
17      NA  140                 NaN 
18      NA  140                 NaN 
19      NA  129             6497352.
20 6497352. 129             6497352.
21      NA  129             6497352.
```

Could someone help me with this complicated issue? Thank you so much!

Comment: You probably have more than 3 rows per Sample_ID (you only have three when you cut it to 21 rows, and thus your code works..). Try `filter(count(mdat_longer_info,Sample_ID), n>3)` to check?

Comment: Yes, and/or you might also add `arrange(SampleID)` before your calculation so that your verification output shows you the relevant rows that make up each group contiguously.

Comment: As others have said, probably you have more than 3 rows per sample ID. You can easily check this by filtering some of the unexpected results, i.e `filter(SampleID == "269")`, you'll probably see where the `203239889` is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for all the previous comments! It is the case that Sample_ID appears more than 3 times (actually, 18300 times). This happened because I transferred the data from the wider to the long format. The solution is to use group_by for multiple columns that distinguish each record that used to be in the wider format. Thanks again for the help, langtang, Jon Spring, and guasi!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the previous comments! It is the case that Sample_ID appears more than 3 times (actually, 18300 times). This happened because I transferred the data from the wider to the long format but removed other identifiers (Sample_ID is just one of the identifiers).

```r
mdat_longer_info2 = mdat_longer_info %>%
  group_by(
    Sample_ID, 
    mz,
    time,
    mz.min,
    mz.max,
    NumPres.All.Samples,
    NumPres.Biological.Samples,
    median_CV,
    Qscore,
    Max.Intensity,
    Batch
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    mean_value = mean(
      value,
      na.rm = TRUE
    )
  )
```

The solution is to not exclude other identifiers during the pivot_longer process, and then use group_by for multiple columns that distinguish each record that used to be in the wider format. Thanks again for the help, langtang, Jon Spring, and guasi!